# Use WCF DataService in application

Tags: wcf, import, wcf-data-services

I have an MVC 3 application and create my own WCF data service. I imported in application as service references and `service.edmx` was automatically created. But when I try to open it, I only see a generic page:

> The entity data model designer is unable to display in the file you requested.

I push right click on the page and try “Add Code Generation Item...”, it gives me an error:

> Command 'Project.AddNewItem' is not available.

Can I generate `.tt` files in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I found the anser: Is not posible.

And if someone whant to use WCF DataSource, an inportant thing: You can't use a lot of reserved word in linq : like JOIN, GROUP, etc...